# Get list of items that only occur in one of the lists

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a two lists

```
lis1 = ["e", "g", "t"] 
lis2 = ["e", "h", "g"]
```

How would I return lis3 after taking the lis1 and lis2 as my parameters?

```
lis3 = ["t", "h"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the way I would do it is

- let `x` = intersection of `lis1` and `lis2`
- let `a` = difference of `lis1` and `x`
- let `b` = difference of `lis2` and `x`
- result is `a` concat `b`

Here's a quick demo

```
import Data.List

let x = [1,2,3] `intersect` [2,3,4]
=> [2,3]

let a = [1,2,3] \\ x
=> [1]

let b = [2,3,4] \\ x
=> [4]

a ++ b
=> [1,4]
```

This demo uses numbers, but it would work identically with characters or strings.

Comment: And if efficiency is a concern then this mode of operation can be done using `Data.Set`.  Another solution would be to not distribute the difference across the union: `f a b = (a <> b) \\ (a `intersect` b)`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I'm by no means a Haskell expert. You should probably provide this as a separate answer as it's probably better than mine. I'm a noob 90% of the time.